# Adding YTD totals for only months of this year

Tags: reporting-services

I'm designing  a matrix report in SSRS.

To the right of the last column I have a grand total of the sum(s) of a rolling 12 month report. The report user wants another column that totals only months for this year.

My columns are broken down into periods (ex, 201401,201402,201501,201505).

My rows are broken down into hours (ex 40.0, 50.2,65.7).

In my YTD total I only want to count the hours that have the same year as the date they run the report. My formula looks something like this but I'm not married to it:

```
=iif(mid(fields!period.value,1,4) = datepart(dateinterval.year,today()), client_hours,"")
```

Basically if the period is one of 201501,201502,201503,20150 or 201505 then add up all the client hours for the employee, else do nothing. My formula is not working as it is adding up all values just like my grand total of hours going across.

Comment: Try using 0 as the ELSE instead of your empty string (""). And SUM it?
=SUM(IIF(MID(fields!period.value,1,4) = datepart(dateinterval.year,today()), client_hours, 0))

Comment: Good Day Nathan, I tried the formula you suggested and now I get an error. here is the formula: =SUM(IIF(MID(Fields!PERIOD.Value,1,4) = DatePart(dateinterval.year,Today()), Fields!CLIENT_HOURS.Value,"")) Don't know what the error is it just prints error on the screen.

Comment: What's the error? It looks like you are adding a text field to a number. Use **0** instead of empty quotes (**""**) - `=SUM(IIF(MID(Fields!PERIOD.Value,1,4) = DatePart(dateinterval.year,Today()), Fields!CLIENT_HOURS.Value,0))`

Comment: It is working properly I took the ) out and used Nothing in place of "" or 0. Thanks for you input.